# Problem setting up Oscova Bot on static IP address

Tags: localhost, chatbot, static-ip-address

I have tried the bot by training it with SIML and Database. I am facing problem while deploying it on a static IP. When I try to deploy the bot on the URL other than localhost like http://192.168.0.25:8086/bot, it says in Console that Access is denied. Moreover deploying on localhost and deploying it on IIS server using Inetmgr. and then accessing it using the IP address and PORT from the computers on the same domain says Invalid hostname. I am using AJAX to get responses which is working fine on my localhost. But accessing on computers other than localhost says the request has been blocked due to CORS policy. Can you give me some insights of how can I deploy the bot sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with WCF Self Hosted then you will have to make the service work on Cross-Domain.

Your application can utilize some of the CORS found here http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html

Below is a copy of the configuration I've used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime
        maxRequestLength="2147483647"
        executionTimeout="300" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="Work.Server.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, Work.Server, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Work.Server.WorkService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Work.Server.IWorkService" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
          <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have tried by adding web config file to my project. But the problem persists. I want to host the server on static IP as I mentioned in the question description. It says access denied.

Comment: I had a recent encounter with this situation and I was able to solve it by first disabling the firewall and testing a response. Later I tweaked the firewall to add the process as an exception.

Comment: In my case the problem was with http features configuration in windows features. I tuned it and it's working fine.